# Display arrow head for an animated line

Tags: css, html, webkit

I am animating a line from Point 1 to Point 2 with https://jsfiddle.net/arungeorgez/r9x6vhcb/4/. How do I add an arrowhead to the same line?

```
<style>
  .key-anim1 {
    -webkit-animation: Drawpath 1s linear forwards;
    animation: Drawpath 1s linear forwards;
    stroke-dasharray: 0, 600;
  }

  @-webkit-keyframes Drawpath {
    from {
      stroke-dasharray: 0, 600;
    }
    to {
      stroke-dasharray: 600, 600;
    }
  }
  @keyframes Drawpath {
    from {
      stroke-dasharray: 0, 600;
    }
    to {
      stroke-dasharray: 600, 600;
    }
  }
  </style>
```

Comment: What is your technical difficulty? Is it difficult to calculate the correct coordinates of the path or the timing? All you need to do is draw the arrowhead. Have you tried ***anything*** regarding drawing the arrowhead itself?

Comment: The arrow head can be drawn but how can it be animated along with the line?

Comment: You have a limited set of options and you should pick the one you like. You can either start two lines from the end of the arrow itself after you finish the arrow, you can treat the entire composition as a drawing and imagine it's uncovered by a piece of paper (so you'd start drawing the two small lines as you get close to the arrow's head) or you could draw the arrow head separately, after finishing the arrow, as you would with a pen (starting from one of the sides, going to the arrow head and then finishing it in the other side).

Comment: Updated the code to include the arrow head.

Comment: Solution B can be applied also to the case where, instead of having two small lines as arrow head you want an area there (with one or two triangles, depending on the type of arrow head you want).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<animate attributeType="XML" 
         attributeName="opacity" 
         from="0" to="1" 
         dur=".08s" begin=".23s" 
         repeatCount="0" fill="freeze" 
/>
```

seems to produce a decent effect for your case, since the arrowhead is small. However, for a more fine-tuned solution one could use `<animateTransform>` or `<animateMotion>`, instead of `<animate>`, depending on case.

Here's the spec for [SMIL Animations](https://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-smil-animation-20010904/).

While the effect is easily achievable with CSS animations (in the end, I'm only animating `opacity` above), I tend to recommend SMIL Animations for `<svg>`s, as they provide a lot more options for controlling the different aspects of animations, far superior to CSS options, IMHO.

```js
function makeSVG(tag, attrs) {
  var el = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', tag);
  for (var k in attrs)
    el.setAttribute(k, attrs[k]);
  return el;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var line = makeSVG('line', {
    id: "-",
    class: "key-anim1",
    x1: 20,
    y1: 20,
    x2: 120,
    y2: 120,
    stroke: 'black',
    'stroke-width': 2,
    'marker-end': "url(#arrow)"
  });
  document.getElementById("svg").appendChild(line);
});
```

```css
.key-anim1 {
    -webkit-animation: Drawpath 1s linear forwards;
    animation: Drawpath 1s linear forwards;
    stroke-dasharray: 0, 600;
  }

  @-webkit-keyframes Drawpath {
    from {
      stroke-dasharray: 0, 600;
    }
    to {
      stroke-dasharray: 600, 600;
    }
  }
  @keyframes Drawpath {
    from {
      stroke-dasharray: 0, 600;
    }
    to {
      stroke-dasharray: 600, 600;
    }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<svg height="600" width="600" id="svg">
  <defs>
    <marker id="arrow" markerWidth="10" markerHeight="10" refX="0" refY="3" orient="auto" markerUnits="strokeWidth" opacity="0">
      <path d="M0,0 L0,6 L9,3 z" fill="#000" />
      <animate attributeType="XML" attributeName="opacity" from="0" to="1" dur=".08s" begin=".23s" repeatCount="0" fill="freeze" />
    </marker>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

**Note:** the easy way to fine-tune ***any*** animation is to decrease the speed 10 times. This way you'll be able to make it perfect, and to increase it back after you're happy with how it performs 10 times slower. Sometimes, when speeding it back up you need to make minor adjustments from how it would be "technically correct" to counterbalance optical illusions (but this is often times far into the land of "invisible details").

---

If you want the maker to be visible and move along with the line, you need to drop the dasharray (because now your line has the same length from start to end of animation, but it's drawn with a dashed line and you're simply moving the gaps in that dashed line so it looks like it's growing). Instead you need to **make it** short initially and animate it towards being longer.

Here's an example:

```html
<svg height="600" width="600" id="svg">
  <defs>
    <marker id="arrow" markerWidth="10" markerHeight="10" refX="0" refY="3" orient="auto" markerUnits="strokeWidth">
      <path d="M0,0 L0,6 L9,3 z" fill="#000" opacity="0">
        <animate attributeType="XML" attributeName="opacity" from="0" to="1" dur=".1s" repeatCount="0" fill="freeze" />
      </path>
    </marker>
  </defs>
  <line id="-" x1="20" y1="20" x2="21" y2="21" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" marker-end="url(#arrow)">
      <animate attributeType="XML" attributeName="x2" from="21" to="120" dur="1s" repeatCount="0" fill="freeze" />
      <animate attributeType="XML" attributeName="y2" from="21" to="120" dur="1s" repeatCount="0" fill="freeze" />
  </line>
</svg>
```

Comment: Yes, any attribute can be animated in SVG as long as it has same type of values and they are animatable (don't expect a string to be animated into another string, though)... I added an example.